# Mavericks: Install gcc while keeping clang as default compiler

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, clang, osx-mavericks

I know that by default `clang` is the C default compiler on Mavericks, and I would like to keep that default. Now, there will be times I still need to compile with traditional `gcc`. My question is: how should I install `gcc` so that my default compiler is still `clang`?

- If I install `gcc` by MacPorts, when I call `gcc` in Terminal it will no longer be symlink to `clang` but actually GNU `gcc`. This is not what I want.
- I do not want to use Homebrew because I do not want to mess with `/usr/local/bin`.

Thanks!

Comment: `gcc` is gcc, as it should be. "Default compiler" is `cc`.

Comment: `port select --set gcc none`